# useState is not updating the desiring state?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to create an accordion of FAQ page and `useState` is updating the icon from + to - on 'true' state but not toggling the answers. It was working fine but suddenly it stopped.
Here is my code.

```
import {React,useState} from 'react'

const AccordianCard = ({question, answer}) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className="card" >
        <div className="question_heading">
          {" "}
          <h3>{question}</h3>{" "}
          <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>

          { show ?   <i className="fas fa-minus"></i> : <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
          } 
          </button>{" "}
        </div>
        
        {
            show && <p>{answer}</p>
        }
    
        
      </div>
    )
}

export default AccordianCard
```

Comment: can you show the full component code?  it would be good to find the issue.

Comment: This should work. Although a better way to toggle would be to `() => setShow(show => !show)`